# How to post Image with status in Facebook in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

HI Guys,

Here I am having problem that How can I post an image including status in facebook can anyone suggest this.

The code I used for posting the status with the inage is as shown below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[args setObject:status forKey:@"caption"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:args dataParam:imageFromCorkit];
```

where imageFromCorkit is a NSData argument which contains the image data.

But i didn't get these posts in my facebook  account.

Thank you,
Monish

Comment: Guys please give me Quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must post the image to your photos (using the method you are doing now, without the args) and then post a wall post that links to the photo.

Comment: Can u have any reference code for the suggestion u had given.

Comment: Hey Guys,
I donno how to post the text with the Images in the facebook integration of my application can any one suggest me about this with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you give [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare) a try, a simple lib I wrote.

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Simple sharing via Facebook, Email and Twitter for iOS!" 
                        descriptionText:@"Posting to Facebook, Twitter and Email made dead simple on iOS. Simply include BMSocialShare as a framework and you are ready to go." 
                        andHref:@"https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare"];    

[post setImageUrl:@"http://www.blockhausmedien.at/images/logo-new.gif" 
         withHref:@"http://www.blockhaus-media.com"];

[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```