# How to Share an Image to facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, share

How to share an image from an iPhone application to facebook?

I am greatly appreciative of any guide or help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post images on facebook wall on a single button click from an iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351830/) or [Post Image with status in Facebook in Iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437574/) or [How to post images with text in facebook integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498398/) or [send mesage to facebook profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637252/) or [post images on facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351830/) among [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+%5Biphone%5D+image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Ray Wenderlech tutorial on how to use the new Facebook graph API.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Now once you have got the user giving you persmission, in your case it would be publish_stream. You can call the graph API with the parameters to post a photo on the wall.

You will need to dig into the developers help guide to find accurately the Graph api which meets your requirement. You will have to then use the accesstoken got from  the first step to make the subsequent calls.

Comment: @Praveen S: thanks for the reponse i am trying that asap and let you know.

Comment: @Praveen S: I have something to ask, I have successfully uploaded imgaes into the user facebook account, but the Question why when the iphone user have already installed the facebook app it opend automaticly? i can i prevent this?

Comment: And how can that be done by code? I am willing to post it as new question if you think it's not related to this Question, many thanks

Comment: you mean safari `cookie storage `?

Comment: "why when the iphone user have already installed the facebook app it opend automaticly?" you mean it opens facebook app to login the user? or does it open some other time?

Comment: @Arcantos: `you mean it opens facebook app to login the user?` Yes Exactly or even if he is already logged in, the app opnes, I am Positive

Comment: I managed to prevent that behavior by changing a couple lines in Facebook.m, if that is fine for you I'll tell you which ones.
Although I would prefer if you create a new question, just to get the accepted answer :P
Also if this answer resolved your previous issue you may consider accepting it, to credit Praveen

Comment: @Arcantos: I posed new Quesition regarding the issue listed above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155934/can-i-prevent-facebook-iphone-app-from-opening-when-using-facebook-sdk-from-my-ap

Answer (score 1):

You always HAVE to open the Facebook app first (or a WebView in case the App is not installed) to get a login token. Try using [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare) which is a simple lib I wrote. It helps you sharing images and normal posts to Facebook, Twitter or Email. It let's you upload some local image (and even open a dialog for the user to add a comment) to the user's wall:

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```

or do something more enhanced:

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Simple sharing via Facebook, Email and Twitter for iOS!" 
                        descriptionText:@"Posting to Facebook, Twitter and Email made dead simple on iOS. Simply include BMSocialShare as a framework and you are ready to go." 
                        andHref:@"https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare"];    

[post setImageUrl:@"http://www.blockhausmedien.at/images/logo-new.gif" 
         withHref:@"http://www.blockhaus-media.com"];

[post addPropertyWithTitle:@"Download" 
           descriptionText:@"github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare" 
                   andHref:@"http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare"];

[post addPropertyWithTitle:@"Developed by" 
           descriptionText:@"blockhaus" 
                   andHref:@"http://www.blockhaus-media.com"];

[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```

Comment: Downloaded and tried your project and getting `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`. Error. Any idea where am i messing it up?

Comment: I am afraid the framework is not working properly. If you integrate the source code rather than the framework, it just works!

Answer (score 0):

first , you need to get permission for publish_stream , otherwise photo share won't show at wall or in album automatically

for detail , you can refer to

http://chings228.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/facebook-ios-login-part-3/