# Can I prevent Facebook iPhone app from opening when using facebook SDK from my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

Can I prevent Facebook iPhone app from opening when using facebook SDK from my app? I don't want to open facebook iphone app.

Comment: so, you want to stick with the old inline dialog for login instead of using single sign on, is that right?

Comment: The Case is I do upload picture to the user facebook account, i did that successfully when the iphone don't have facebook app installed, but when the facebook app is installed the sdk redirects me to the facebook app.

Comment: @AhmadTK: I believe that if you follow the instructions in the facebook SDK readme about setting up a URL scheme for your app then it will redirect back to your app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you not to do that cause from my experience most users won't login to Facebook via your app instead of FB application or browser. They just don't trust third party apps.

edit:

But if you still do not want to use browser/FBApplication you need to change:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
       localAppId:(NSString *)localAppId {
  self.localAppId = localAppId;
  self.permissions = permissions;

  _sessionDelegate = delegate;

  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
}
```

to NO in Facebook.m of FBConnect framework

Comment: Never thought about that. Good answer.